# Display records that have 1 for multiple columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have numerous columns that will output either 1,0 depending on the value in other columns. I have a total of 4 columns that only output either 1 or 0 and I would like to include all records that have 1. This way, I don't have to have all records displayed after a query runs and it will take significantly less amount of time as well.

Here is my SQL statement and the columns that have 1,0 are
Flag for Settled , Flag for Pending, Flag for Dismissed, and flag for no resol.

```
SELECT 
 FLAG1.Account_Name, 
 FLAG1.Claim_ID, Format([flag1].[Org_Clmt_ID],"@") AS Org_Clmt_ID, 
 IIf([FLAG1].[CLAIM_STATUS]="SETTLED" And ([flag1].[indemnity_paid] Is Null Or [flag1].[indemnity_paid]=0),1,0) AS Flag_for_Settled, 
 IIf([FLAG1].[indemnity_paid]>0 And [flag1].[CLAIM_STATUS]="PENDING",1,0) AS Flag_for_Pending, 
 IIf([FLAG1].[indemnity_paid]>0 And [flag1].[CLAIM_STATUS]="PENDING",[FLAG1].[indemnity_paid],0) AS Flag_for_Pending_Amt, 
 IIf([FLAG1].[CLAIM_STATUS]="DISMISSED" And [flag1].[indemnity_paid]>0,1,0) AS Flag_For_Dismissed, 
 IIf(([FLAG1].[Claim_Status]="SETTLED" Or [flag1].[Claim_Status]="DISMISSED") And (([flag1].[Resolution_Date] Is Null And [flag1].[Resolution_Year] Is Null And [FLAG1].[Settlement_Date] Is Null And [flag1].[Status_Date] Is Null)),1,0) AS Flag_For_No_Resol_Date
FROM FLAG1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to repeat the conditions that set those flags, in your where clause, separated by OR (assuming you want a 1 in any of the columns).  You will end up with a long chain of conditions, but you can reduce it some by combining some of the elements -  (A and B) or (A and C) is the same as (A and (B or C)).

Sorry it does not get easier than that, unless someone out there wants to do all that grunt work for you.